# Don't autostart program when using remote desktop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, autostart

I have a program that I want to start at logon but only when I'm physically using my machine. When I'm accessing my machine via remote desktop I want this program not to start automatically.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a batch file to start that program, and check the `SESSIONNAME` environment variable. If you are logged in locally, it will be set to `Console`, otherwise it will be something like `RDP-Tcp#26`.

A batch file can be as simple as this:

```
if "%SESSIONNAME%"=="Console" start notepad
```